Get exaclty the results of Sql Database from any Query from MySqlDataReader
I am trying to make a program that prints the results of any sql query no matter what type the result has.
I am using a MySqlDataReader reader. I already tried reader.GetValue(i), but it returns the error: unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
reader.GetString(i) returns also errors when there are any non-string values.
reader[i].ToString() internally uses GetValue() and so returns the same error.
Inside of the MySqlDataReader, there is a private function GetFieldValue(int index, bool checkNull) which seems to have the wanted behavior, but I cannot access it.
I just want to read values like these exactly how they are stored:



ID
Date/Time
Name
Value




0
2024-09-03 12:01:23
test
0.00



But it either gives me errors, or if I use the GetValue(i) variant, it returns this:



ID
Date/Time
Name
Value




0
03.09.2024 12:01:23
test
0,00



So the date has a different format and floating point numbers use "," instead of "."

Dates have no format, they're binary values. There's no 0000-00-00 date. That's purely a  MySQL quirk that can't be translated to a date in client applications, not just .NET. The real solution according to MySQL's own documentation:  the best solution to the date problem is to restrict users from entering invalid dates. Otherwise, you can enable zero dates through a connection option

According to the Server SQL Mode docs such invalid dates are disabled by default since 5.7, so someone had to explicitly re-enable invalid dates on the server. The best solution is to fix the bad server mode before more bad data enters the database

But what about the 0,00 instead of the 0.00? Is there no general solution no matter if the content is correct or pretty, that just returns the content?

That's how your client application displays the actual data using your locale settings. This has nothing to do with how the data is stored. This has nothing to do with contents and formatting. ADO.NET always returns the actual values returned by the server.

The general solution is to just not store invalid dates

BTW Connector/ODBC returns NULL when a "zero" dates is retrieved. From the docs: “Zero” date or time values used through Connector/ODBC are converted automatically to NULL because ODBC cannot handle such values . For whatever reason Oracle decided to return DateTime.MinValue in Connector/NET and NULL in Connector/ODBC

Okay pls forget the wrong format. I just fixed it now, there were not many of them. But it anyways returns correct dates in wrong format: instead of 2024-09-03 12:01:23 it returns 09/03/2024 12:01:23 and instead of 0.00 it returns 0,00

That's no different than typing Console.WriteLine(3.5) and seeing 3,5 in half the world and 3.5 in the other half. The application that displays the data uses the end user's locale to format the bits into strings

But it makes a difference, when I have a interface, where i put data in, but it needs the data in the format of the database. Isn't there a simple solution like reader.GetValue(i) to get the content without using the end user's locale to format the bits into strings? Or can i set it to the same, where 0.00 stays 0.00 and 2024-09-03 stays like that?

This has nothing to do with the database. You're asking how to change the culture of your application. You can use eg Thread.CurrentCulture=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"); in a WinForms or WPF app. ASP.NET automatically detects the browser's preferred language from the request headers but you can change the culture at the page or web app level too. DON'T assume your end users expect dots though, especially in Europe. Developers may prefer the US format but business users expect to see their local format. If a user in France stores 123 plus change, they expect to see it as 123,456

That's not specific to .NET anyway, all Windows applications work this way. If you want to use a different locale, it's a good idea to have the user select the one they want. Instead of hard-coding "fr-BE" or "en-AU" you can store the string as an application setting, or create a combo where the user can select the culture they want.
